# Django - Como apresentar último valor cadastrado no banco de dados em uma tela de cadastro

Tags: django, django-admin

Sou novo e ainda enfrento dificuldades que possam parecer bem simples pra vocês.
Resolvi por motivos pessoais fazer uma aplicação em Django.
Ela é um simples cadastro de pessoas num banco de dados MySQL usando django adminLTE, adminLTE_theme:

**em models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Pessoas(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='nome completo')
    registro = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='número do registro')
    
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'pessoas'
        verbose_name = 'Filiado'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Filiados'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

**em admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Pessoas

@admin.register(Pessoas)
class PessoasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nome', 'registro')
```

No acesso da página de cadastro na área administrativa, gostaria de ter uma linha (row, ou qualquer coisa) que apresentasse o número do último registro cadastrado.

Já tentei fazer cópia do template *change_form.html* e direcionar pra esse html:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Pessoas

@admin.register(Pessoas)
class PessoasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nome', 'registro')
    add_form_template = 'cad_filiado.html'
```

e no html:

```
{% block field_sets %}
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Pessoa</th>
                    <th>Registro</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for p in pessoas %}

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ p.pessoa }}</td>
                        <td>{{ p.registro }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

até copiei o código do *change_list_result.html* no cad_filiado.html e dá erro de reverse_url...
tentei várias coisas, li e reli a documentação e não achei resposta. (Talvez a resposta até esteja lá, mas eu não entendi como executar)

Talvez você possa se perguntar: por que vc quer essa informação na página de cadastro?

R.: Pra manter uma usabilidade agradável, sem que precise procurar os registros.

agradeço a paciência.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era um problema bem simples de resolver mas que não tinha nada a ver com o que estava lendo pra tentar resolver.

Basicamente: criei uma tag e usei na cópia do html do template de *change_form.html* que tinha feito.

**Passo 1:**
Criei um diretório dentro da pasta do *app* com o nome **templatetags**

**Passo 2:**
Criei um arquivo dentro do diretório novo chamado **filiado_utilitario.py**

**Passo 3:**
Fiz os importes, registros e uma busca no banco de dados:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def pesquisa_filiado():
    from django.db import connection
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(""" SELECT registro FROM pessoas ORDER BY id DESC limit 1;""")
        ult_pessoa = cursor.fetchone()
    return ult_pessoa[0]
```

**Passo 4:**
no *cad_filiado.html* acrescentei o importe do arquivo *.py*

`{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify filiado_utilitario %}`

**Passo 5:**
fui até o arquivo *.virtualenvs/Meu_Projeto_Estudo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html* e copiei o trecho:

```
<fieldset class="module aligned {{ fieldset.classes }}">
     <div class="form-row"> 
     </div>
</fieldset>
```

e inseri a tag logo depois do começo do formulário:

```
<form {% if has_file_field %} enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %}
      action="{{ form_url }}" method="post" id="{{ opts.model_name }}_form" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% block form_top %} 
<fieldset class="module aligned {{ fieldset.classes }}">
     <div class="form-row"> 
     Uĺtimo Filiado cadastrado número: {% pesquisa_filiado %}
     </div>
</fieldset>
```

e fim.

Dá pra escovar um pouco mais e aceito sugestões